# CSP issues in a project with react router and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am making a React app where I use React router, and on the backend nodejs + express. My task, when contacting http://example.ru, I give one react application, and when http://example.ru/admin another. The problem is that if I go to http://example.ru/shop via react router (NavLink) my CSP settings work. But if I use the browser address bar, then the CSP settings do not work, or rather they work only on http://example.ru.

My CSP settings
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src http://localhost:3001 https://sun9-23.userapi.com https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net https://gspics.org data:">`

Error if you go to http://example.ru/shop through the browser address bar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMV9b.png

In browser developer tools, there is a meta tag.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S15C7.png

Comment: What index.html is being returned by the server when visiting `example.ru/shop` directly, Is it different from `example.ru/`?

Comment: @Aivaras No, this is 1 html document

Comment: Shouldn't `*` be quoted like `default-src '*';` Also provided CSP policy contradicts what is visible in the last screenshot (there is no fallback policy)

Comment: Also `meta` tag is one thing, but there might be response headers set on html document which is not obvious from your question.

Comment: @Holing Homan, you have 2 different CSPs published at the same time. I have answered this you question at [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227806/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-csp-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81-react-router-%d0%b8-nodejs/1228149#1228149) part in your native language.

Comment: Please add the answer below in the answer space. Do not add it in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load an external image, you need to include its domain in the `img-src` policy, which in this case is `https://i.stack.imgur.com`.
You should also replace `http://localhost:3001` with `'self'`.

Your `meta` tag should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src 'self' https://sun9-23.userapi.com https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net https://i.stack.imgur.com https://gspics.org data:">
```